# WatchKit App only returning some HealthKit Data

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, healthkit, hksamplequery

I have the below method running in both my IOS app and my WatchKit App (Xcode 7 GM).  The IOS app returns all of my running workouts, however the Watchkit app returns only the first 2 running workouts.

Any idea?

```
func readRunningWorkOuts(completion: (([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {

    // 1. Predicate to read only running workouts
    let predicate =  HKQuery.predicateForWorkoutsWithWorkoutActivityType(HKWorkoutActivityType.Running)
    // 2. Order the workouts by date
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    // 3. Create the query
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(), predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
        { (sampleQuery, results, error ) -> Void in

            if let queryError = error {
                print( "There was an error while reading the samples: \(queryError.localizedDescription)")
            }
            completion(results,error)
    }
    // 4. Execute the query
    healthKitStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)

}
```

Comment: What is the source associated with the workouts?  Which device were the workouts saved on?  How old are the workouts?

Comment: Saved on the watch and they were on the past 2 months.  New workouts show up just not those older ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the last 7 days worth of data is available from HealthKit on the watch.  Any workouts that were created earlier than that will only be on the phone.  See the [HKHealthStore reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614166-earliestpermittedsampledate) for more information.